# How to get number and sum of values of specific id (average) inside blade?

Tags: php, laravel

Template:

```
<div class="item-wrapper" style="text-align:justify; top: 100px;">
    <legend>Reviews</legend>
    @if (count($reviews)>0)
        @forelse($reviews as $review)
            @if( $review->counselor_id == $cprofile->id)
                {{$review->review}}
                {{$review->rating}}
                <star-rating :rating="{{$review->rating}}">
                </star-rating>
            @endif @empty
        @endforelse
    @endif
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$relations = [
    'viewCprofile' => counselor::all(),
    'reviews' => DB::table('counselor_reviews')
        ->select('*')
        ->get()
];

return view('viewCprofile', $relations);
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/viewCprofile', 'ProfilesController@getCprofiles');
```

Should I pass id to controller to get data?

Comment: Hey Hafizur! Welcome to SO! You should probably do that in your controller and then pass it to your blade. Can you show us your controller logic?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to place that logic in there and not in a comment? Also - last thing - would you be able to update your question with your route being used to view the blade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following and complete your code

```
    @if (count($reviews)>0) 
                @php $total_ratings = 0 @endphp
                @forelse($reviews as $review) 
                    @if( $review->counselor_id == $cprofile->id) 
                        @php $total_ratings += $review->rating @endphp

                        {{$review->review}} {{$review->rating}} 

                        <star-rating :rating="{{$review->rating}}"> </star-rating>
                            {{$total_ratings}}
            @endif
```

Comment: Okay, Will it work for specific id? I can't do it in controller

Comment: if won't work if i don't put ($reviews as $review), take a look at the code

Comment: ` @if (count($reviews)>0)
                            @forelse($reviews as $review)



                            @if( $review->counselor_id == $cprofile->id)
                            $total_ratings = 0
                            {{$review->review}}
                            {{$review->rating}}
                            $total_ratings += $review->rating
                            <star-rating :rating="{{$review->rating}}">
                            </star-rating>
                            echo $total_ratings
                            @endif` it is hsowing as string

Comment: yes it gave me total rating, how can i get the average for that counselor?

Comment: You can take a variable outside for each loop and increment it inside loop and divide total rating by this number

Comment: It's solved . Thanks . Do you know how to show the ratings as stars?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/display-a-stored-value-1-5-as-a-star/